# How can you capture this with regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to capture a conditional of years in RegEx. Basically, if they implement just a two digit year, I want to make it a four digit year. So if they put :

```
1/2/08
```

I want to make it :

```
1/2/2008
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One [pretty nasty] way using regex:

```
"1/2/08".sub! /\/(\d{2})$/, '/20\1'
```

Wouldn't it be better to just parse the string into a date object, though? Then you can treat it as a date properly! :)

Comment: I thought you could. But if you Date.parse("1/2/09"), it's completely different than Date.parse("1/2/2009")

Comment: Careful with this. If you do get "1/2/2008", the substitution will return nil.

Comment: @steve-wilhelm `sub!` returns nil but modifies the original variable

Answer (score 1):

You could split on '/' and if the last component has a length of two you prepend 20 and then assemble the date again.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string up using

```
(.*/)(..)$
```

and then substitute with something like

```
$120$2
```

to put the string back together (tested with http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/).

You might need to think about what you want to happen for dates in the 20th century - this approach will recognise 21/01/98 as 21/01/2098 which might not be what you want... It might be better to parse the string out properly rather than just blindly regex it!